# Xcode block (NSMallocBlock) indentation (braces automatically starting from new line)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, objective-c-blocks, indentation

I want to open blocks with braces starting at new line.

Let's move away from philosophical discussion of whether this is a good decision or not -- `regardless of 'where' and 'when', 'how' remains absolute.`

So, the problem is described below:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this?

---

I was looking around for quite a while, but I didn't find any solutions.

I am already aware of such things as:

1. [Snippet Edit](http://cocoaholic.com/snippet_edit/) -- this little program will allow to edit default Xcode's code snippets. So, you will be able to open braces from new line in your `if`, `for`, `while`, etc. However, this doesn't allow to change the block indentation.
2. [Uncrustify](http://blog.manbolo.com/2015/05/14/code-beautifier-in-xcode) -- this might solve my problem, but it doesn't look like being easy to set up. And it only formats the code **after** it is already written, instead of formatting **'on the go'**. Moreover, even if I set `uncrustify` correctly, it will still be quite slow -- about 4 mouse clicks are required to format the block, which is time consuming.

Is anybody aware of any other solutions?

**EDIT:**

To be more specific, I want the block to be indented **as soon as** I press `ENTER` on this step:

[image]

Comment: Xcode enforces one specific style. You cannot change it without plugins.

Comment: @Sulthan, do you know any plugins, which could help with the issue?

Comment: The problem is that you cannot setup common style formatters even to format in this style. The style is so specific that nobody implemented options that would enable it. And that includes writing Obj-C in other IDEs.

Comment: @Sulthan I prefer this style, too. And I do not know, whether {} at the beginning of a newline is really specific. I would call it a classical style for brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution that i've found is this:

Download [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) and change your `private.xml` (you can also view documentation [here](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/xml.html.en))

Your `private.xml` may look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <item>
        <name>Command+Enter to complete single block</name>
        <identifier>private.swap_cmnd+Enter_to_complete__single_block</identifier>
        <autogen>
            __KeyToKey__
            KeyCode::RETURN, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L | ModifierFlag::NONE,
            KeyCode::RETURN,

            KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L,
            KeyCode::DELETE, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L,
            KeyCode::BRACKET_RIGHT, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L,
            KeyCode::BRACKET_RIGHT,
            KeyCode::SEMICOLON,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_UP,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_UP,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT,
            KeyCode::RETURN,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L,

            KeyCode::CURSOR_UP, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_UP, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_UP, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L,

            KeyCode::I, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_UP,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L,
            KeyCode::TAB,
        </autogen>
    </item>

    <item>
        <name>Option+Enter to complete double block</name>
        <identifier>private.swap_Option+Enter_to_complete_double_block</identifier>
        <autogen>
            __KeyToKey__
            KeyCode::RETURN, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L | ModifierFlag::NONE,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT,
            KeyCode::RETURN,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_UP,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L,
            KeyCode::TAB,

            KeyCode::RETURN,

            KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L,
            KeyCode::TAB,
            KeyCode::RETURN,
            KeyCode::DELETE,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L,
            KeyCode::DELETE, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L,
            KeyCode::BRACKET_RIGHT, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L,
            KeyCode::BRACKET_RIGHT,
            KeyCode::SEMICOLON,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_UP,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_UP,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT,
            KeyCode::RETURN,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_UP,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_UP,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_UP,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_UP,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT,
            KeyCode::RETURN,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L,

            KeyCode::CURSOR_UP, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_UP, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_UP, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_UP, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_UP, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_UP, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_UP, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L,

            KeyCode::I, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_UP,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_UP,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_UP,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_UP,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_UP,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L,
            KeyCode::TAB,
        </autogen>
    </item>
</root>
```

After this is done, you can now open the block by pressing `⌘`+`ENTER` (**instead** of pressing `ENTER`, when opening the block, press `⌘`+`ENTER`). Here is the [preview](https://youtu.be/LNFz5EED4cQ) (slowed down, so that you see details).

The above works with single blocks only. If you want to open two blocks at once, you can press `ALT`+`ENTER`. Here is the [preview](https://youtu.be/CAYeCIVqga4) (slowed down, so that you see details).

Here is the [preview](https://youtu.be/rbZw5WGF2G0) with the actual speed:

[image: Demo CountPages alpha]

Answer (score -1):

Just manually put you **starting brace** into a new line, then your indentation should be good.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think there is a way to do that automatically after you press `ENTER`.

What you *can* do, is hit `ENTER` to let it fill the snippet, and then go before `{` and hit `ENTER` again. Xcode formats it the way you like afterwards.